# How to choose system user ID for custom packages (RedHat & compatible)?

Tags: rhel, rpm, useradd

How should I choose the proper `uid` (or `gid`) for system users being created in a custom .rpm package?

The user will be used to run a daemon non-root.

I think it's not acceptabe to let `adduser` choose the next ID by omitting `--uid` because this could create a conflict with fixed `uid`s of official packages. Further, this could lead to different IDs across multiple systems, making further administration harder.

Are there ranges of unused and unreserved `uid`s that can be used (as far as they're not reused in the local environment)? Is there a algorithm to generate a `uid`/`gid`?

This question applies to RedHat EL 6+, CentOS 6+ and Fedora. The package's .srpm or .spec should get published.

Answer (score 1):

The [RHEL6 migration guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Migration_Planning_Guide/sect-Migration_Guide-Security_Authentication-System_users.html) documents that there's a list for statically-assigned UIDs in `/usr/share/doc/setup-*/uidgid`, which currently goes up to roughly 200, and dynamic system users count downwards from 499.

I read that as "use `adduser -r` in this case and certainly don't worry if you stay above 300; you won't collide unless you have hundreds of system users".

Answer (score 1):

Letting `adduser` choose a user ID *is* the right way to do it. This won't conflict with official packages because automatically-assigned UIDs and statically-assigned UIDs are in different ranges. Yes, this does lead to different user IDs across systems; there's no easy way to do that because you'd have to tell the whole world (every system administrator and package writer) “don't use this user ID, it's mine”.

Specifically, use `adduser -r` so that the user will be created in the range reserved for automatically-assigned system accounts. This way, the UID will not conflict with other dynamically-allocated UIDs (because `adduser` picks one that doesn't already exist) nor with statically-allocated UIDs or UIDs of flesh-and-blood users (because they're in different ranges).

For more information, see the [Fedora packaging guide](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:UsersAndGroups?rd=Packaging/UsersAndGroups).